# finding the first letters after the replaceAll() in j.s

Tags: javascript, string

hi how can we find and access the first letters that comes right after the replaceAll() ?
like we have : hi_my name is_reza => replaceAll("_"," ") => so now i want to access to (m) from my and to (r) from reza

id did try split() and indexOf() method but it just aiming one of underscores not all of them

Comment: Just out of curiosity... why would you ever want to need this? What's that you're building exactly?

Comment: i want to make all the first letter that come after ( _ ) to become capital and it remove under scores

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? What does "i want to access to (m)" mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split`, `slice` (start from index 1 to the end, because you don't want the left part of the first '_') and `map` (which execute over every element of an array) on `hi_my name is_reza` like so :

```js
const str = "hi_my name is_reza";
const d = str.split("_").slice(1).map(e =>e[0]);

console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

The get the first character(s) after `_` *underscore*, you could use:

```js
const str = "hi_my name is_reza";
console.log(str.match(/(?<=_)./g))
```

or with `/(?<=_)[^_]/g`

[Demo on Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OwMkCY/1)

To change that letter after `_` (in order to capitalize it) and remove the underscore all in one go, you could use [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) like:

```js
const str = "hi_my name is_reza";
const output = str.replace(/_(.)/g, (m, m1) => ` ${m1.toUpperCase()}`)
console.log(output)
```

Comment: i want to make all the first letter that come after ( _ ) to become capital and it remove under scores

Comment: @Dude too bad you did not explained it immediately :) Anyways, edited my answer to improve on the needed requirement

Answer (score 1):

> By this, you can do both replace and get those string after _

```js
let str = 'hi_my name is_reza';
let res = [];
const final = str.replaceAll(/_/g,function(r,index){
  res.push(str[index+1]);
  return ' '
});

console.log(final,res)// by this you can replace and get the string after _
```

Answer (score 0):

### thank you all . actually i was looking for a way to remove all underlines and replacing the first letter after them to be capital . so i used your solution to achieve that .

```js
const str = "hi_my name is_reza";
const d = str
  .split("_")
  .map((word, index) => {
    return index !== 0 ? word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1) : word;
  })
  .join(" ")
  .replaceAll("_", " ");

console.log(d);
```

Comment: This is an overkill - just use `.replace()` instead. See my edited answer.

Comment: thank you yes your approach is shorter and better :)